# UWP ListView - How to update BringIntoView to show part of next item, in both directions

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I am working on a listview of items and I need to allow user to scroll up/down but I need the bring into view handling to bring the item into view as well as a small part of the next item (in scrollviewer extent).  This will indicate to user that there is an item above or below in the list.

I have made a simplified sandbox app to work on this and here are screenshots of what I am trying to do. Arrow indicates scroll direction and the red parens indicate the part I cannot get to show up, meaning the partial amount of the next item.
[image]
[image]

Please ask if you need anything clarified, I understand this is a complex explanation.

What I have tried:

- margin (+/-) on ItemsPresenter/ScrollViewer/ListView
- handling `ListView.SelectionChanged` and using math and various logic to determine direction of scroll and then use `ScrollViewer.ChangeView` call with calculated vertical offset value.
- handling `ListView.BringIntoViewRequested` and set `args.Handled = true` and issue new request with various `BringIntoViewOptions` values, including `VerticalOffset`, `VerticalAlignmentRatio`, and new `TargetRect` with adjusted `Y` value.

I have read several helpful existing questions here on SO that led me to the `BringIntoViewOptions` attempt. But nothing so far has worked.

None of these have worked. If I could describe what I want it would be to utilize the existing `BringIntoView` functionality but bring the item far enough into view that the next item shows a little.

Comment: The scrollbar has the function of reminding the user whether there are list items up and down. Why would you want to implement something like this?

Comment: Well I am not sure why that matters but to answer your question the vertical scrollbar is hidden in our UX design and the required behavior is to show the next item (if it exists) partially. Certainly wouldn't do this just for the heck of it.

Comment: If you want to get the effect you want, you may need to overwrite the logic of scroll and calculate the location of items by yourself.

Comment: that is what i did

Comment: Could you please provide your OS version and a sample project that reflects your current real scenario. I'll try to see if we could find a way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Can `ListView.ScrollIntoView` meet your needs?https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/XamlListView/cs/Scenario6_ScrollIntoView.xaml.cs#L28

Comment: In the end I was able to cobble together a solution in the selection changed event but it involved using dispatch calls and delaying them by a few ms to get them to actually show up. This proved buggy at best though did work most of the time. In the end I trashed it all and just used scroll into view method and gave up on the req. to see a little of the next item.